# rectangle block deformed after thresholding

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

here is what I have now

```
//Thresholding
Mat mat2 = mat.clone(); //mat is origin picture
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat2, mat2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold(mat2, mat2, -1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY+ Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU); 

//Erosion and Dilation
Mat element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1));
Imgproc.dilate(mat2, mat2, element);
element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1));
Imgproc.erode(mat2, mat2, element);
```

I make a program to detect the rectangle block. After thresholding, the rectangle blocks become weird.

Is there have anyway to make a good effect of threshold or fix it?

---

### Update

cut from Origin image, dpi is low.

[image]

After Threadholding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try first to apply some blur to get rid of noise and test the threshold again if still does not work there is an OpenCV [page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html) with examples how to denoise.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to sharpen your image. There are many many methods for this, but I don't know which ones are implemented in OpenCV.

For example, using GIMP's [unsharp mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking) tool (parameters 300, 5, 0), I get a result which may be easier to threshold:

[image: Sharpened]